# Vb.net bitmap function error

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I have constructed this sprite class in vb.net it all checks out ok to me except for 1 error

```
 Public Sub drawbitmap(ByRef bmp As Bitmap,
                      ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single,
                      ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer)
    p_device.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, x, y, width, height)
 End Sub
```

This isn't my code it's from a book i bought if i'm correct this function should be managing the overflow for  this bitmap image
  game.drawbitmap(grass, 0, 0, 800, 600)
I i it's managing the overflow for the sprite as well yet it is saying its value is null. Which is odd because ik this it declared correctly i even checked by looking at other very malarial functions within the sprite class. I also re referenced the book multiple times and retyped it. so any advice on whats wrong would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Please include the full error message.

Comment: here is the error message. Argument cannot be nulll.